# unresolved external symbol when implementing memory management template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, pool

I'm trying to create a pool to manage the allocation and so on of little game objects that will die and reborn quickly.

For it I have created a Pool:

```
template <class T>
class Pool {

public:

    T* obtain()
    {
        T* obj = 0;

        if (_avaibles.size() > 0)
        {
            std::vector<T*>::iterator it = _avaibles.begin();
            obj = *it;
            _avaibles.erase(it);
        }
        else
            obj = new T();

        return obj;
    }

    void free(T* obj)
    {
        _avaibles.push_back(obj);
    }

    void clear()
    {
        std::vector<T*>::iterator it = _avaibles.begin();

        while (it != _avaibles.end())
        {
            T act = *it;
            delete act;
            ++it;
        }
    }

private:

    std::vector<T*> _avaibles;

};
```

The problem is I'm getting unresolved external symbols. The pool is placed as a static member of a class:

```
 static Pool<Ship> _shipPool;
```

Here is the error:

```
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: 
static class Pool<class Ship> Asdf::_shipPool"  
(?_shipPool@Asdf@@0V?$Pool@VShip@@@@A)  C:\-\Asdf.obj
```

Comment: Please provide the exact wording of the error message you are getting (if it is a stack/core dump, we just need the relevant bits).

Comment: the title of the question and the issue raised are very different from each other...

Answer (score 2):

You can't split up a template like that. Put the implementation into the `.hpp` file and everything's shiny.

Refer to [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) for futher information.

Comment: You are right. Now is giving me this: cannot convert from Ship** to Ship*

Comment: That's because you're interface is not right. As an exercise, do the template instantiation once on paper to see which types you have for your variables. Hint: `new T` is `new Ship*` in your case. You might also want to head over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com since there are more flaws in your implementation.

Comment: @filmor: Code Review will only work when the code functions.

Comment: Thanks again. I fixed that but still, now it cannot resolve the "external symbol private: static class Pool<class Ship> ..."

Comment: What did you fix? You have moved the whole implementation into the header file? Would you please refresh the question or post a new one with your current code?

Comment: Ah, well now you have the problem the other way round. If you have a static member of a class you have to *define* it in exactly one implementation file. So in `asdf.cpp` add a line `static Pool<Ship> Asdf::_shipPool;`.